# TextView with 3 lines has different height depending on amount of filled lines

Tags: android, textview

I have the following TextView:

```xml
<com.mycompany.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/productName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="3"
    android:maxLines="3" />
```

This results in an expected look of the TextView with different amounts of text:
[image: TextView with different amounts of text]

However, when I use our corporate font created by our company, the TextView is getting bigger with every line with no text:
[image]

I don't know how this can be dependent on the used font. Is there any attribute in the .ttf file that leads to this odd behaviour?

My first thought was that Android adds new paragraphs to the TextView if not all of the lines are filled. But it would be new to me that a font file can define a default paragraph spacing.

Comment: Both images look like same,

Comment: @DhavalSolanki I changed the image

Answer (score 0):

As your view has height and width as "wrap_content" with max_lines = 3. Now it's quite obvious that view's dimensions will change depending as it will figure it out that how much height it will need to accommodate three lines of specific type (font) of input text

Answer (score 0):

As you have custom Textview.Calculate and update LayoutParams dynamically based on the aggregate height of each line.
Yes Text size will vary based on font types.
Check [this](https://medium.com/@tuanchau/text-and-font-size-on-android-1894dab350df) for detail explanation.

Vote if it helps.

Thanks. Happy coding.

Comment: shouldn't the calculation be taken over from the parent class?